# What is the name of this plug? (with images)

Tags: audio, hardware

I have speakers that connect with the plugs shown in the images below to a hifi system, but I would like to connect them instead directly to a computer. Before I can find some kind of adapter to make that possible my question is what the name of this plug is, and if it is some standard?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about signal processing.

Comment: ... or move it somewhere appropriate - [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com)?